# StackOverflow exception thrown - not sure how to fix it

Tags: c#, stack-overflow

I've written a program in C#, using Microsoft Visual Studio.

I apologize in advance that there is a lot of code - I've not been able to solve the problem using other peoples StackOverflow solutions, and I figured the problem is somewhat a specific error in every code.

I've tested my code continuously while writing, and the parser part works fine - the StackOverflow problem appeared when I implemented the class SvfStatements:

```
class SvfStatements
    {
        FtdiDevice ftdiDevice = new FtdiDevice();
        StatePath statePath = new StatePath();

        // variables for IR
        public byte[] SirTdi
        {
            get { return SirTdi; }
            set { SirTdi = value; } // Problem occurs here
        }
        public byte[] SirMask
        {
            get { return SirMask; }
            set { SirMask = value; }
        }
        public byte[] SirSmask
        {
            get { return SirSmask; }
            set { SirSmask = value; }
        }
        public bool sirTdoEquality
        {
            get { return sirTdoEquality; }
            set { sirTdoEquality = value; }
        }

        public bool SIR(int length, string fromState, string toState, string endIR, byte[] tdo)
        {
            // Finding TMS vector

            // Declaring enums from/to states
            StatePath.States eFromState, eToState;

            // Converting from string to enum
            Enum.TryParse(fromState, out eFromState);
            Enum.TryParse(toState, out eToState);

            // Finding the first part of the tms vector, where we move to the state we need, in order to do a data register scan
            bool[] tmsPathOne = statePath.FindPath(eFromState, eToState);

            // We want to stay in this state while handling the TDI, and inits an array in the length of the TDI vector
            bool[] tmsPathTwo = new bool[length]; // Since the default value for a bool[] is "false", we won't have to make any changes to it

            // The last state we go to is the stable state for DR
            string currentState = toState;
            Enum.TryParse(currentState, out eFromState);
            Enum.TryParse(endIR, out eToState);
            bool[] tmsPathThree = statePath.FindPath(eFromState, eToState);

            // Shift state
            if (length > 0)
            {
                // Masking tdi with smask
                SdrTdi = MaskingArray(SdrTdi, SdrSmask);

                // We need empty tdi arrays to send along the tms array
                bool[] sdrTmiOne = new bool[tmsPathOne.Length];
                bool[] sdrTmiThree = new bool[tmsPathThree.Length];

                // We currently have our main tdi in bytes, but need it in bool to concat them
                bool[] sdrTmiTwo = SdrTdi.SelectMany(GetBits).ToArray();

                // Concatting our tms and tdi arrays
                bool[] tmsBool = tmsPathOne.Concat(tmsPathTwo).Concat(tmsPathThree).ToArray();
                bool[] tdiBool = sdrTmiOne.Concat(sdrTmiTwo).Concat(sdrTmiThree).ToArray();

                // Converting from bool to byte array
                byte[] tmsByte = Array.ConvertAll(tmsBool, value => value ? (byte)1 : (byte)0);
                byte[] tdiByte = Array.ConvertAll(tdiBool, value => value ? (byte)1 : (byte)0);

                int byteLength = tmsByte.Length;


                // Sending data to ftdiDevice, recieving a tdo array back
                byte[] recievedTdo = ftdiDevice.Shift((int)byteLength, tmsByte, tdiByte);

                // Testing the recieved tdo
                if (tdo == null)
                {
                    // No tdo declared - a comparison with the recieved tdo will not be performed
                }

                else
                {
                    // A tdo was declared, and will be compared to the recieved tdo
                    // Testing equality 
                    sirTdoEquality = AreEqual(recievedTdo, tdo, SdrMask);

                }

                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The length of the SDR command was 0, no data was shifted.");
                return false;
            }

            // Methods used
            bool AreEqual(byte[] ftdiTdo, byte[] svfTdo, byte[] svfMask)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < ftdiTdo.Length; i++)
                {
                    if ((ftdiTdo[i] & svfMask[i]) != (svfTdo[i] & svfMask[i])) return false;

                    Console.WriteLine("The TDO's doesn't match.");
                }

                Console.WriteLine("The TDO's match.");
                return true;
            }

            byte[] MaskingArray(byte[] inputArray, byte[] maskingArray)
            {
                byte[] outputArray = null;

                for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.Length; i++)
                {
                    outputArray[i] = Convert.ToByte(inputArray[i] & maskingArray[i]);
                }

                return outputArray;
            }

            IEnumerable<bool> GetBits(byte b)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
                {
                    yield return (b & 0x80) != 0;
                    b *= 2;
                }
            }
        }


    }
```

The code that is calling this class (the get set of `byte[] SirTdi`) is this one:

```
case "SIR":
                                    // Performs an IEEE 1149.1 Instruction Register scan
                                    Console.WriteLine("Got command: " + command);

                                    PIOMAP_allowed = false;
                                    trst_absent_allowed = false;

                                    string[] parameters_sir;
                                    char[] delimiter_sir = new char[] { '(', ')' };
                                    int lengthSir = Convert.ToInt32(statement[1]);
                                    byte[] sirTdo = new byte[] { };

                                    if (lengthSir > 0)
                                    {
                                        Console.WriteLine("The amount of bits sent in the message is: " + lengthSir);
                                        for (int p = 2; p < statement.Length; p++)
                                        {
                                            parameters_sir = statement[p].Split(delimiter_sir, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                                            if (parameters_sir[0] == "TDI")
                                            {
                                                svfStatements.SirTdi = ConvertHexStringToByteArray(parameters_sir[1]);
                                                foreach (byte b in svfStatements.SirTdi)
                                                {
                                                    Console.WriteLine("The tdi array is: " + b);
                                                }


                                            }

                                            else if (parameters_sir[0] == "TDO")
                                            {
                                                sirTdo = ConvertHexStringToByteArray(parameters_sir[1]);
                                                foreach (byte b in sirTdo)
                                                {
                                                    Console.WriteLine("The tdo array is: " + b);
                                                }
                                            }

                                            else if (parameters_sir[0] == "MASK")
                                            {
                                                svfStatements.SirMask = ConvertHexStringToByteArray(parameters_sir[1]);
                                                foreach (byte b in svfStatements.SirMask)
                                                {
                                                    Console.WriteLine("The mask array is: " + b);
                                                }
                                            }

                                            else if (parameters_sir[0] == "SMASK")
                                            {
                                                svfStatements.SirSmask = ConvertHexStringToByteArray(parameters_sir[1]);
                                                foreach (byte b in svfStatements.SirSmask)
                                                {
                                                    Console.WriteLine("The smask array is: " + b);
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }


                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        Console.WriteLine("The amount of bits sent in the message is: " + lengthSir);
                                    }

                                    // Handling data

                                    // Handle data 
                                    svfStatements.SIR(lengthSir, currentState, command, stableStateEndir, sirTdo);

                                    // Sets the new current state
                                    currentState = stableStateEndir;
```

The error message recieved is:

[image: StackOverflow exception]

[image: StackOverflow exception command window]

As far as I understand is, that such errors occurs when a function/line of code is called infinetly many times, thus causing the stack to overflow. However, I don't understand what is being called infinetly in this case?

Comment: asked bazilion times ... search for stackoverflow in getter/setter

Comment: Basically you need to declare all your properties in this this form: `public byte[] SirTdi { get; set; }` . All your properties are declared in a way that causes a stack overflow as you are using the same property inside the getters and setters.